# How do I close the terminal window after running a shell script from AppleScript?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript

I have created the following in AppleScript and although it works when I double click the compiled app, I am left with an empty Terminal window in the dock which seems to remain until I forcibly quit it. So, how can I simply run the given command and close the terminal while the application (vboxmanage) is still running?

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "vboxmanage startvm MyWindows; exit;"
end tell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following, if you don't want a Terminal window involved and the program is able to function without Terminal:

```
do shell script "vboxmanage startvm MyWindows"
```

The actual AppleScript will wait for the command line program to quit though. I like it best when used as a *Service* via Automator.